# How can I make a Windows 8 style layout using CSS3?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a Windows 8 'tile'-style layout using HTML with CSS3 and am having some trouble. I drew a little diagram to convey what I am trying to achieve -- the problem is that this layout is very easy to achieve vertically, but not horizontally.

[image]

### Here is a vertical example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tAdjY/

```css
#container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
 display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
#container > section {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex: none;
  -webkit-flex: none;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  -ms-flex: none;
  /* IE 10 */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

### But here, if I try to make it horizontal (same markup, different CSS), it gets smushed:

http://jsfiddle.net/tAdjY/1/

```css
   #container {
     width: 320px;
     height: 320px;
     overflow: scroll;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -moz-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
     flex-flow: row nowrap;
   }
   #container > section {
     display: flex;
     -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
     flex-flow: column wrap;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     margin-right: 20px;
   }
   #container div {
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 90px;
     height: 90px;
     margin: 5px;
     background: blue;
   }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

I don't know if there's a real solution for this or if flexbox is just limited, but I look forward to any decent answers. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that in webpages, horizontal scrolling is *horrendous*.

Comment: Oh, how I know, but this is intended for a television with a remote control (think TV guide.)

Comment: Found a relevant question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058404/how-to-use-css3-flexbox-to-create-multi-column-layout-without-expanding-vertical

Comment: Another that was so close but did not work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516246/windows-8-flexboxes-nesting-flexboxes-with-overflow-enabled?rq=1